# Function in while loop / php

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop

I have to send some Users a private Message. Therefore I make a select to the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `phpbb3_users` WHERE `user_email` LIKE '%testmail@online.com%'"; 

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```

**The select has 17 results.**

Then I use this function to send a private Message to each user_id

```
include($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_privmsgs.' . $phpEx);

function sendphpbbpm($pmmessage,$mid,$pmsubject) {

global $config, $db, $user, $auth, $template, $phpbb_root_path, $phpEx;

$message = utf8_normalize_nfc($pmmessage);
$uid = $bitfield = $options = ''; // will be modified by 
generate_text_for_storage
$allow_bbcode = $allow_smilies = true;
$allow_urls = true;
generate_text_for_storage($message, $uid, $bitfield, $options, 
$allow_bbcode, $allow_urls, $allow_smilies);
$pm_data = array(
'from_user_id'      => '45148', //Community
'from_user_ip'      => '127.0.0.1',
'from_username'     => 'Community',
'enable_sig'        => false,
'enable_bbcode'     => true,
'enable_smilies'    => true,
'enable_urls'       => false,
'icon_id'           => 0,
'bbcode_bitfield'   => $bitfield,
'bbcode_uid'        => $uid,
'message'            => $message,
'address_list'        => array('u' => array($mid => 'to')),
 );

//Now We Have All Data Lets Send The PM!!
submit_pm('post', $pmsubject, $pm_data, false, false);
}
```

**In the while loop I use the function call:**

```
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{

$mid = $row['user_id'];
$pmsubject = 'Test Subject';
$pmmessage = 'Test';

sendphpbbpm($pmmessage,$mid,$pmsubject);

}
```

The problem is: Only the first user_id get a private message and no one else. Any Ideas?

Comment: nothing obvious is there. Can you please post variable dump of $result and each $row? maybe there is something wrong

Comment: Thank you. When I make a "echo $row['user_id'];" in the while, I see only 2 rows, when I remove the function call, the echo give me 17 rows. I am pretty sure it has something to do with double arrays or something like that.

Comment: var_dump($row);  = array(1) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(6) "105616"
}
array(1) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(5) "35229"
}

Comment: and what is the content of $result?

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#13 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(6)
  }
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(13)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
object(mysqli_result)#13 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(13)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: I will bet that the problem is in using the same name for variables in the same scope. Can you please post all the code as it is written. Not only the parts.

Comment: Thank you very much for getting into with me. I am pretty sure you are right. I made already a testfile with only this code. There is nothing more. I think it has something to do with the "$pm_data = array(" in the function. I deleted step by step everything and this is the last thing that gives the error.

Comment: 'address_list'        => array('u' => array($mid => 'to')) is not in the loop

Comment: I think think this is close. What do you suggest to get it into? How to write? thank you daniel

Comment: submit_pm, is likely doing a db request and breaking your initial db fetch loop (perhaps $db->sql_freeresult).  Try fetching all data in advance.  i.e. get all your user_ids upfront.